# How do I copy code from python into GitHub?

Tags: python, github

I am trying to copy and paste my code from a web server which was written in python into a new file on GitHub.

I go to my github repository (https://github.com/markus24135/ibmdatascience) and click "add file" then "create new file". Once a new file opens, I paste the code directly in there. However, the code doesn't become color coded as I would see in python (like import doesn't turn green) and when I save the file and then click on it again, I get this error message: "Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?".

Even when I reload I can't get the code to show up. I thought you could just copy and paste code into github instead of pushing it from python to github? Do I have to figure out how to push it?

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: You're going to need to figure out how to push, pull, stash, and do other git operations eventually, so you may as well start learning now. Get the book at https://git-scm.com and start learning!

Comment: When creating the file, please make sure its name ends with ".py" as an extension in order for Github to understand that it is a Python code.

Comment: I've checked your repository and all files show up normally and color coded. The workflow you've followed is supposed to work (however far from ideal, as others cited).
Maybe you're having browser issues. I'd try clearing the cache and logging in again.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the "add file" feature, what I do to get code into github is:

1. create a git repository using `git init`
2. Add the remote github repository using `git remote add origin git@github.com:markus24135/ibmdatascience.git`
3. run `git add -A`
4. run `git push origin -u main`

Comment: Also, if you’re intimidated by the command line, GitHub offers a GitHub Desktop application for multiple platforms which allows all of this to be done using a GUI. The command line is useful to know and you should learn it eventually for more advanced operations. But GitHub Desktop is a useful way to get started.